# Не понимаю как прочитать dataset c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Считываю файл excel, там 2 строки, хочу проверить что там, а в dataset как будто пусто. При этом никаких ошибок нет.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileStream);
                    DataSet ds = reader.AsDataSet();
                    Console.WriteLine(ds);
                    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: через отладчик смотрите, и не используйте `Console` в винформах, есть же `Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: в экселе может быть несколько листов. можно посмотреть, а есть что-нибудь в текущей таблице: Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count);